# Why does the Batman "crack his knuckles" in "Batman: Arkham Origins"?

Tags: dc, batman, arkham-series

Wouldn't cracking his knuckles be futile through his thick glove armor and in what way, if at all, would it help Batman in delivering a beatdown? I believe it would hinder his grappling efficiency and render him less dextrous.

**Why does Batman "Crack His Knuckles" in *Batman: Arkham Origins* and in *Batman: Arkham City*?**

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KnuckleCracking

Comment: Why would cracking knucles hinder his grappling efficiency and render him less dextrous?

Answer (score 29):

Batman usually cracks his knuckles to [show that he's deadly serious](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KnuckleCracking). He does it in other media as well.

> [image]
>   <sub><sup>[Batman The Animated Series Episode 32 - Robin's Reckoning, Part I](https://batmantheanimatedseries.fandom.com/wiki/Robin%27s_Reckoning_Part_I/Dialogue)</sup></sub>

and

> [image]
>   <sub><sup>[JLA #3 - War of the Worlds](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/jla-3-war-of-the-worlds/4000-43508/)</sup></sub>

Purely for the record, cracking your knuckles [helps with joint looseness](https://www.hopkinsarthritis.org/arthritis-news/knuckle-cracking-q-a-from/) and may help to prevent injury to your hands during a fight.

Comment: A related fun fact, as we might want to know if this would lead Batman to get arthritis as he gets older.  One Dr. Ungler spent 50 years cracking the knuckles on only his left hand at least twice a day...and found ["There was no arthritis in either hand, and no apparent differences between the two hands."](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/1529-0131%28199805%2941%3A5%3C949%3A%3AAID-ART36%3E3.0.CO%3B2-3)

Comment: @BruceWayne Has that experiment been reproduced? A sample size of one is a bit small.

Comment: @JAB - Given that he won an ignobel award for it, I'd assume the answer is no, but they've also done cohort studies on people (including siblings and twins) who've never cracked their knuckles or crack them regularly.

Comment: @JAB - Agreed, but that's why it's a "fun fact" and not "scientific fact" :P

Comment: @JAB the sample size is two! Two hands, one in each group. :)

Comment: @hobbs true enough!